# Can you explain the CPU sleep/wake up code

Tags: c, assembly, event-handling, cpu, msp430

This is code for my wdt_handler.s

```
    .file   "_wdt_handler.c"
.text
    .balign 2
    .global WDT
    .section    __interrupt_vector_11,"ax",@progbits
    .word   WDT
    .text
    

    .extern redrawScreen
    .extern wdt_c_handler
WDT:
; start of function
; attributes: interrupt 
; framesize_regs:     24
; framesize_locals:   0
; framesize_outgoing: 0
; framesize:          24
; elim ap -> fp       26
; elim fp -> sp       0
; saved regs: R4 R5 R6 R7 R8 R9 R10 R11 R12 R13 R14 R15
    ; start of prologue
    PUSH    R15
    PUSH    R14
    PUSH    R13
    PUSH    R12
    PUSH    R11
    PUSH    R10
    PUSH    R9
    PUSH    R8
    PUSH    R7
    PUSH    R6
    PUSH    R5
    PUSH    R4
    ; end of prologue
    CALL    #wdt_c_handler
    ; start of epilogue
    POP R4
    POP R5
    POP R6
    POP R7
    POP R8
    POP R9
    POP R10
    POP R11
    POP R12
    POP R13
    POP R14
    POP R15
    cmp #0, &redrawScreen
    jz  ball_no_move
    and #0xffef, 0(r1)  ; clear CPU off in saved SR
ball_no_move:   
    RETI
    .size   WDT, .-WDT
    .local  count
    .comm   count,1,1
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.9.1 20140707 (prerelease (msp430-14r1-364)) (GNUPro 14r1) (Based on: GCC 4.8 GDB 7.7 Binutils 2.24 Newlib 2.1)"
```

This is code for my main.c

```
void main()
{
  P1DIR |= GREEN_LED; /**< Green led on when CPU on */
  P1OUT |= GREEN_LED;

  configureClocks();
  lcd_init();
  shapeInit();
  p2sw_init(15);
  buzzer_init();
  shapeInit();

  clearScreen(COLOR_WHITE);

  enableWDTInterrupts(); /**< enable periodic interrupt */
  or_sr(0x8);            /**< GIE (enable interrupts) */

  for (;;)
  {
    while (!redrawScreen)
    {                      /**< Pause CPU if screen doesn't need updating */
      P1OUT &= ~GREEN_LED; /**< Green led off witHo CPU */
      or_sr(0x10);         /**< CPU OFF */
    }
    P1OUT |= GREEN_LED; /**< Green led on when CPU on */
    redrawScreen = 0;
    drawString8x12(0, 70, "Welcome to Lab", COLOR_RED);
    drawString8x12(65, 75, "3", COLOR_RED);
    randomDraw(50, 20, COLOR_BLACK);
    drawRand(100, 150, COLOR_BLACK);
  }
}

void wdt_c_handler()
{
  u_int switches = p2sw_read();
  static short count = 0;
  P1OUT |= GREEN_LED; /**< Green LED on when cpu on */
  count++;
  if (count == 15)
  {
    stateAdvance_(); // assembly function not related to cpu
    count = 0;
  }
  P1OUT &= ~GREEN_LED; /**< Green LED off when cpu off */
}
```

I understand in the wdt_handler.s we do a comparison for redraw screen if they're both zero then what line is executed next? what is the `and #0xffef, 0(r1)` doing?

Im struggling to understand how the cpu wakes up and sleeps, I know this is very vague but anything helps.

Comment: Where did you get this code from? Why does it use assembler when it would not be necessary? And what exactly do you not understand from the comment on that line?

Comment: that instruction and #0xffef, 0(r1) is zeroing a bit.  anything anded with a 1 is itself anything anded with 0 is 0  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND_gate